# How to migrate all AWS services (including running instance, API, Snapsorts) to its sub account with consolidate Billing?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have one master AWS account and have linked one subaccount with it. I want to migrate all AWS services (including running instance, API, Snapsorts, user group permissions, tags, etc)  to subaccount with consolidated billing.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

AWS CloudFormation allows you to achieve the goal you described by saving your infrastructure to a JSON-based template. After that, you will be able to deploy resources from the template on any other region or account.

You can find more details here:

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html